# Construct an explicit bijection $f:[0,1] \to (0,1]$, where $[0,1]$ is the closed interval in $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1]$ is half open.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

**The problem:**

Construct an explicit bijection $f:[0,1] \to (0,1]$, where $[0,1]$ is the closed interval in $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1]$ is half open.

**My Thoughts:**

I imagine that I am to use the fact that there is an injection $\mathbb N \to [0,1]$ whose image contains $\{0\}$ and consider the fact that a set $X$ is infinite iff it contains a proper subset $S \subset X$ with $\lvert S \rvert = \lvert X \rvert$ (because we did something similar in class). I also have a part of proof that we did in class that I believe is supposed to help with this problem; it states the following: Start with an injection $g: \mathbb N \to X$ and then define a set $S=F(X)$ where $F$ is an injective (but NOT surjective) function $X \to X$ with $F(x) = x$ if $x \notin \text{image}(g)$ and $f(g(k)) = g(2k)$ if $x=g(k) \in \text{image}(g)$. Honestly, I'm having a lot of trouble even following this proof, so I could be wrong. Anyway, any help here would be appreciated. I feel really lost on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

define $x_0 = 0$ and $x_n = 1/n $ for $n \geq 1$ ... define $f:[0,1] \to (0,1]$ $f(x)= x $ if $  x\neq x_i , i\geq 0$ and $f(x_i) = x_{i+1} , i \geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Partition $[0,1]$ into two subsets:

$$
A \;\; =\;\; \left \{0, \left .\frac{1}{2^n} \; \right | \; n \in \mathbb{N}\right \}
$$

and the complement $A^c$.  Define $f:[0,1] \to (0,1]$ by

$$
f(x) \;\; =\;\; \begin{cases}
x, & \text{if} \; x \in A^c \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if} \; x = 0\\
\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, & \text{if} \; x = \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{cases}.
$$

It should be relatively straightforward to check injectivity and surjectivity.