# mapping of the real line to interval [0,1)

Tags: real-numbers

What is a mapping (bijection) of the real line (−∞,∞) to the interval [0,1)? I'm trying out logs and exponentials but they don't seem to work?

Comment: Can you map the real line to $(0,1)?$  There are a number of functions that work for that.  Then you just need to map $(0,1)$ to $[0,1)$.  You can't do that continuously, but it is not hard to do.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to map real line to (0,1), but dont know how (0,1) to [0,1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1) Also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233238/construct-an-explicit-bijection-f0-1-to-0-1-where-0-1-is-the-closed?rq=1)

Comment: Or this one: [Explicit bijection between [0,1)
and (0,1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425492/explicit-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

What about the following function:
$$f(x)=\tanh|x|$$

Comment: This is not a bijection.

Comment: @RossMillikan bijectivity was not required in the original question.

Comment: In original required continuous and edited to bjection.

Comment: @Botond Im sorry, I changed the question, but thank you.