Is there a bijection between [0, 0.5] and (0.5, 1]?
An approach I tried was to define the bijective function f:[0, 0.5] -> (0.5, 1] as,
f(x) = x + 0.5
and although this is surjective, it being injective makes the choice of adding 0.5 to x in the function seem arbitrary.
I understand that the way I have constructed the bijection is probably wrong, but I cannot figure out what the right way is.

What is $f(0)$ for your $f$?

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1233238/42969

Does this answer your question? Proving intervals are equinumerous to $\mathbb R$  The reference from Martin R is a better duplicate and has links to more.

The bijection can't possibly be continuous.  The set $[0, 0.5]$ is compact and the continuous image of a compact set is continuous.  Since $(0.5, 1]$ is not compact, no continuous map can be surjective.

Not an elegant bijection, but the simplest one to think about: $f:[0,0.5] \rightarrow (0.5,1]$ is defined as
$$f=\left\{\begin{split}
x+0.5 &\quad x\not\in\mathbb{Q} \\
L_2(i) &\quad x\in\mathbb{Q}, x=L_1(i)
\end{split} \right.$$
where $L_1$ is the sequence of all rational numbers in $[0,0.5]$ and $L_2$ in $(0.5, 1]$
